# jquery - hide unchecked radio button using submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide all unchecked radio button and its label then display only the checked radio button using the submit button click event.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn">
    <label for="first">First</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn">
    <label for="second">Second</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn">
    <label for="third">Third</label><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to make this work using jQuery. Can anyone give me snippet of jQuery code on how to do this?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted solve the problem with to the question. Also just FYI, it would be a *much* better idea to do what you require under the `submit` event of the `form`, instead of the `click` of the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something simple like this

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submission
  $('[name="radiobtn"]:not(:checked)') // get all unchecked radio
    .hide() // hide them
    .next() // get all label next to them
    .hide(); // hide the labels
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="radiobtn">
  <label for="first">First</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radiobtn">
  <label for="second">Second</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radiobtn">
  <label for="third">Third</label>
  <br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. it works.

Comment: @kenphanith glad to help :)